# Joomla Module install uninstall file doesn't load while installing

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, extensions, installation

I have a module which has some DB Functions during installation 
for which i have made the reference 

install.mysql.utf8.sql

uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql

in the mod_score.xml (mod_score is the name of the module)

**mode_score.xml**
It shows 
**" installing module was successful "** but checking the database there are no tables installed .
please let me know how to solve 
I have searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118623/joomla-module-install-mysql) but didnt work

```
<files>
    <filename>mod_score.xml</filename>
    <filename module="mod_score">mod_score.php</filename>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
        <folder>tmpl</folder>
        <folder>sql</folder>
        <folder>sql/mysql</folder>
        <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/form_success.php</filename> 
        <filename>sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</filename>
        <filename>sql/mysql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</filename>
</files>
<install>
        <sql>
         <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
        </sql>
</install>
<uninstall> <!-- Runs on uninstall -->
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
</uninstall>
```

**install.mysql.utf8.sql**

```
  DELIMITER $$

-- Match Records 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `#__match_record` (
 `match_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ---
     ---
 `match_comments` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=122 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
-- Batting Records

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `#__batting_record` (
 `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pname` varchar(40) DEFAULT 'DNP',
 ---
 ---
 `timeinserted` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=244 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

-- Bowling Records
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `#__bowling_record` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `no` int(10) NOT NULL,
 ---
 ---


 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Version - Joomla 3.+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify subfolders and files in folders what you already have specified. Just use `<folder>tmpl</folder>` and `<folder>sql</folder>`.

No need for `<folder>sql/mysql</folder>` etc. Whole folder is already being installed.

Your `<files>` tag would be.

```
<files>
    <filename>mod_score.xml</filename>
    <filename module="mod_score">mod_score.php</filename>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <folder>tmpl</folder>
    <folder>sql</folder>
</files>
```

Now, your problem. Remove `DELIMITER $$` and `END $$ DELIMITER ;`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20363676/1960712) for clarification. There has to be `;` in end of every mysql query if you have multiple queries in one file.

Your `sql` should look like this:

```
-- Match Records 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `tst_match_record` (
 `match_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `match_comments` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=122 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
-- Batting Records

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `tst_batting_record` (
 `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pname` varchar(40) DEFAULT 'DNP',
 `timeinserted` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=244 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Bowling Records
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `tst_bowling_record` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `no` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: those --- in the create table was just to avoid writing all the excessive columns in the code ! And your solution worked right !

Comment: Okay. Sorry, now I understand.